# Filtrar Dataset a partir de um groupby

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, pandas, numpy, filtro

Tenho o seguinte dataframe (df_reviews) e preciso remover as versões do App que foram baixadas menos que 10 vezes e tentei fazer os passos abaixo e um *for* para realizar o filtro no dataset original, mas não obtive exito
Abaixo coloquei o passo-a-passo do meu caminho...

[image: df_review]

Pelo "App Version Name" fiz um filtro para avaliar quantas vezes cada versão foi baixada:

`App_version = df_reviews.groupby('App Version Name').agg({'Star Rating': ['mean', 'min', 'max', 'count']})`

E o resultado foi o seguinte:

[image: agg]

Após isso criei uma condição para limpar o df_reviews, onde a versão com menos que 10 downloads devia ser dropada do df:

`condicao1 = df_reviews['App Version Name'].value_counts() < 10`

[image: cond1]

E para filtrar o df_reviews, fiz um *for* para remover as linhas cujo a versão possui menos de 10 downloads, mas o *for* não está dando certo.

````
for i in range (0, df_reviews.shape[0]):#buscando em linha por linha
    if df_reviews.at[i, "App Version Name"] == condicao1:#serve para acessar o label
        df_reviews['Teste1'] = df_reviews['Teste1'].append(condicao1.loc[[i]])```
````

Comment: Tente `df_reviews[df_reviews['App Version Name'].isin(condicao1[condicao1 == False].index)]`. Isso escolhe os nomes que estão entre os que são False em condicao1.

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado (E muito mais prático)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente

`df_reviews[df_reviews['App Version Name'].isin(condicao1[condicao1 == False].index)]`

Isso escolhe os nomes que estão entre os que são `False` em condicao1. – Jorge Mendes 1 hora atrás

por Jorge Mendes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/150167/jorge-mendes